# Jquery Datepicker returns wrong month JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, datepicker

I have a datepicker object on my page, it works fine, but when I handle it in my ManagedBean class, with java util date variable, it returns wrong month of the year, and sometimes with one day different.

There is my datepicker object:

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' ,
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "-70:+0"
         });
```

my xhtml:

```
<h:inputText styleClass="datepicker"
    value="#{registerManagedBean.dateOfBirth}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd" />
</h:inputText>
```

I call my ManagedBean class register method, for the form submit:

```
public void Registration() {
    System.out.println("Registration: " + firstName + ", " + surName + ", "
            + dateOfBirth);
    playerSessionBean.addPlayer(new Player(dateOfBirth, email, firstName,
            height, surName, team, weight));
}
```

Some example input output:

> Selected value: 2014.10.06  ==> Output: 2014.01.05
>   Selected value: 2013.07.10  ==> Output: 2013.01.09
>   Selected value: 2014.03.26  ==> Output: 2014.03.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your `<f:dateTimeConverter />` pattern:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

Unlike date picker widget, here `mm` refers to *minutes* not *months*. It should be:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

See [f:convertDateTime tag reference](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertDateTime.html)